# Prevent double/triple clicking on Done button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to prevent the double/triple clicking issue for my "Done" button in my application.
I have my "Done" button as below in my .jsp file:

```
<ip:button name="Done" 
           text="Done"
           jsEvent="onclick=\"if(submitPage() && doneSubmit()) 
           { request.value = 'DONE_REQUEST'; submit(); }\"" />
```

And the submitPage() is the JavaScript method as below:

```
function submitPage(){
    if (pageLoaded && !hasSubmitted ){
        hasSubmitted = true;
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return ! showWaitMsg();
    }
}
```

submitPage() method is used by other buttons as well.

So I was thinking to using the submitPage() method to disable "Done" button (only the "Done" button) once the button is clicked and enable it once "hasSubmitted = true;".
Can anyone please advise how could I do it?

Comment: where are you having the problem?

Comment: @David I was trying to disable the "Done" button in the JavaScript but it seems not working. 
adding "document.getElementsByName('Done').disabled=true;" in submitPage()